# Safari loading JSON file response 421 error

Tags: javascript, json, apache, safari

I am loading a JSON file inside Safari over POST-methode.

First page load shows the JSON content, all next page loads does **not** load the JSON file again.

Error message inside Safari's console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412 (Precondition Failed)
```

Inside Firefox, Chrome or IE I can load the JSON file as often I want.

It seems there is a solution: http://avnwx.blogspot.co.at/2011/10/debuggers-lie.html

> Seems to me the best solution would be to allow server to return 304 Unmodified... If I send a conditional request and the response hasn't changed from an earlier response, the 304 fits the bill.

How can I tell the server to return `304 Unmodified`?

Answer (score 2):

Change your POST request to GET